# I'm only able to return 1 array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to take this array and split it into 2 new arrays, evens and odds and return them. When I run the code below I am only getting the odds, why is that? And what can I do to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

```
var numbersArray = [1,2,34,54,55,34,32,11,19,17,54,66,13];

function divider( arr ) {
  var evens = [];
  var odds = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 === 0) {
      evens.push(arr[i]);
    } else {
      odds.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return(evens, odds);
}

divider(numbersArray);
```

Comment: Use `return { 'even': even, 'odds': odds };` instead.

Comment: And use destructuring on the caller side: let {even, odds} = numbersArray(...);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because JavaScript can only return one value. Ever.

```
return(evens, odds)
```

evaluates to the same value as

```
return odds
```

due to the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) wrapped in grouping parenthesis.

Perhaps returning an array of arrays (or even an object of arrays) is useful..

```
return [evens, odds]
```

Comment: Except you use continuation passing style, theoretically, I mean, not seriously :D

Comment: @Iven Even with CPS (or generators on the other end), an expression can only ever yield one value.

Comment: No, because returning in CPS means calling another continuation, which is a function in Javascript and functions accept several arguments!

Comment: @Iven Each expression supplied as a function argument yields a separate parameter value. This is not in opposition to my statement above. It would still result in the same behavior if using `cb((evens, odds))`; and `cb(evens, odds)` uses two separate expressions to yield different values.

Comment: Yes, I think it does, but it is not worth arguing, because almost no one uses CPS

Comment: @Iven Callbacks are pretty common in some contexts - but about as fine-grained a 'CPS' as used in JavaScript. I've enjoyed playing with ReactJS; it's not CPS and it's not promises, but it allows for quite the elegant handling of streams.

Answer (score 2):

The result of evaluating `(evens, odds)` is `odds`, that is returned thus.
This is how [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) works.

Use the following statement instead:

```
return { 'evens': evens, 'odds': odds };
```

As an example:

```
var v = divider(numberArrays);
v.evens; // get evens this way
v.odds; // get odds this way
```

Answer (score 2):

You should return your results as an array.

```
return [evens, odds];
```

And then to access the results:

```
var evens;
var odds;

var arrayResults = divider(numbersArray);
evens = arrayResults[0];
odds = arrayResults[1];
console.log(evens);
console.log(odds);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, you can only return ONE value. So, if you want to return multiples values, to separate them, you can put them in an array or in an object :

```
 return([evens, odds]);
```

OR

```
return({evens: evens, odds: odds})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return only one entity from a function. Its better to wrap your results in single object.

```
  var numbersArray = [1,2,34,54,55,34,32,11,19,17,54,66,13];

    function divider( arr ) {
      var evens = [];
      var odds = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 === 0) {
          evens.push(arr[i]);
        } else {
          odds.push(arr[i]);
        }
      }
      return {evens:evens, odds:odds};
    }

    divider(numbersArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Es5 doesn't support tuples, You should wrap your return

in an object like here

```
 var numbersArray = [1,2,34,54,55,34,32,11,19,17,54,66,13];

    function divider( arr ) {
      var evens = [];
      var odds = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 === 0) {
          evens.push(arr[i]);
        } else {
          odds.push(arr[i]);
        }
      }
      return {evens:evens, 
    odds:odds};
    }

   divider(numbersArray);
```

Or in an array as the other aswers show

Answer (score 1):

You could return an object, like this:

```
var numbersArray = [1,2,34,54,55,34,32,11,19,17,54,66,13];

function divider( arr ) {
    var evens = [];
    var odds = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 === 0) {
            evens.push(arr[i]);
        } else {
            odds.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return {evens, odds};
}

divider(numbersArray);
```